# Setting an integer to an enum variable

Tags: c#, enums

I have this enum:

```
public enum IndexType : int
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The value has not been set.
        /// </summary>
        NotSet = 0,
        /// <summary>
        /// No description available.
        /// </summary>
        _1moUSDLIBORBBA = 1,
        /// <summary>
        /// No description available.
        /// </summary>
        _12moUSDLIBORBBA = 71,
        /// <summary>
        /// No description available.
        /// </summary>
        _3moUSDLIBORBBA = 12,
        /// <summary>
        /// No description available.
        /// </summary>
        _6moUSDLIBORBBA = 13,
        /// <summary>
        /// No description available.
        /// </summary>
        USDPRIMEH15 = 1896,
        /// <summary>
        /// No description available.
        /// </summary>
        USDSIFMAMunicipalSwapIndex = 3,
    }
```

I want to create a variable of this enum type and set it equal to an integer like this:

```
Data.Indications.IndexType indexType = sm.FloatingComponent.IndexID.Value;
```

That's not compiling though. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enums in C# allow casting to and from int.  Assuming IndexID.Value is an int, it is as simple as:

```
Data.Indications.IndexType indexType = (Chatham.Web.Data.Indications.IndexType)sm.FloatingComponent.IndexID.Value;
```

Comment: Tried that, got this -> Error 68 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Chatham.Enumerations.IndexType' to 'Chatham.Web.Data.Indications.IndexType'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Sounds like a namespace issue, you have two types sharing the same name 'IndexType'.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: @slandau: In that case, you have two enums named `IndexType`: `Chatham.Web.Data.Indications.IndexType` and `Chatham.Enumerations.IndexType`. The unqualified `IndexType` cast is resolving to the second, so just change `(IndexType)` to ` `(Chatham.Web.Data.Indications.IndexType)`.

Comment: Sounds like you have two enumerations named `IndexType` in two different namespaces. If it makes sense, you might want to consider renaming one of those.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure what values come from IndexID then use this code:

```
        if (sm.FloatingComponent.IndexID.HasValue && Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Data.Indications.IndexType),sm.FloatingComponent.IndexID.Value))
        {
            Data.Indications.IndexType indexType = (Data.Indications.IndexType)sm.FloatingComponent.IndexID.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            Data.Indications.IndexType indexType = IndexType.NotSet; 
        }
```